# Why do same data-typed variables give different responses?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, azure-cognitive-services

I am using *azure-cognitive-services* sending some image and get some response, having a problem with the 'bytes' data type.

I sent an image that loaded by `open(image_path, "rb").read()` which has type `<class 'bytes'>` and send the request by `requests.post(emotion_recognition_url, params=params, headers=header, data=byted_image)` where data has definition: `:param data: (optional) Dictionary (will be form-encoded), bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the :class:'Request'.` and everything is good and works fine.

When I tried to send the image that is captured from `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` which returns `numpy.ndarray` then it's converted to bytes by `np.ndarray.tobytes(image)` so that its dtype is `<class 'bytes'>` and is sent to the endpoint by `requests.post()` it returned with error that is **"{'error': {'code': 'InvalidImage', 'message': 'Decoding error, image format unsupported.'}}"**.

Notes:

I have also tried sending the order attribute of `np.ndarray.tobytes()` by 'C', 'F' and even None and nothing worked.

When I save the frame with `cv2.imwrite()` and re-read the image again with `open(image_path, "rb").read()` it works but that's not the best solution.

Comment: I don't understand this: `but of course it's much useless effort`.

Comment: I mean it takes much time certainly. I edited that for more clarification.

Comment: It's easy to understand, the bytes generated by `np.ndarray.tobytes` only contains the information about pixels while the one read from file also contains image header information. They are totally different. Maybe you can try use `io.BytesIO` to handle `cv2.imwrite()` and get bytes from it. In this case, you don't need to write hard disk.

Comment: Thanks for help, but it gives the same error 'Decoding error, image format unsupported.'